# Fio disk test which block size to chose for mysql?

Tags: mysql, hard-drive, filesystems, rdbms

If my fs use 4k block size, mysql use 16k page size. But which block size to choose for fio  test?

Comment: What is the goal of the test?  Disk performance for MySQL?  Are you comparing two filesystems?  Two hardwares?  Something else?

Comment: Yes, the goal is disk performance for mysql. We have a performance issue on stages, guess it is disk issue, need to correctly compare environments. But other than that, I want to understand this parameter in general and how does it relates to fs blocks and mysql blocks.

Comment: Use 16KB.  But excessive I/O can _often_ be fixed by improving the indexes and/or reformulating queries.  Start by identifying the naughty queries:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for a vague indication of MySQL InnoDB
I/O performance - 16KB.

If you are looking into storage stack tuning, you should probably start with [tuning storage alignment](https://shatteredsilicon.net/blog/2020/08/18/mysql-mariadb-innodb-on-non-zfs/).